# How to run Blockly Maze?

Tags: blockly

I'm trying to figure out how to run the [Blockly Maze game from GitHub](https://github.com/google/blockly-games).

I found some instructions on the [wiki page of that repository](https://github.com/google/blockly-games/wiki/Build) to build it somehow. But I can't figure out how I have to do it.

Could you guys point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: What steps are you getting stuck at? Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: Not important anymore, but thanks for asking. ;)

Comment: Others may still have the same problem in the future, so if you have the time to make your question clear, it can be answered as a resource for the community.

Comment: @ggorlen that's true. But I cannot remember and do not work on that project anymore, sorry.